# Cannot install Red Hat git

Tags: git, perl, redhat, rhel

I have a strange situation that I cannot install git on my new Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5 64-bit platform

```
$> yum install rh-git29
```

I get this:

> Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
>   Resolving Dependencies
>   ...Error: Package: rh-git29-git-2.9.3-3.el7.x86_64 (rhel-server-rhscl-7-eus-rpms)
>              Requires: perl(Term::ReadKey)
>   Error: Package: rh-git29-perl-Git-2.9.3-3.el7.noarch (rhel-server-rhscl-7-eus-rpms)

So I tried to install perl and got this now:

```
$> yum install rh-perl5261!
```

> Error: Package: 4:rh-perl526-perl-devel-5.26.1-404.el7.x86_64 (rhel-server-rhscl-7-eus-rpms)
>              Requires: systemtap-sdt-devel

What package is `systemtap-sdt-devel` in?

Comment: `systemtap-sdt-devel` *is* a package. It provides introspective facilities for Linux systems. [This should help](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/systemtap_beginners_guide/using-systemtap#using-setup)

Comment: Can't install either one as its not in a package

systemtap systemtap-runtime

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Term::ReadKey is not a core Perl module, so I wouldn't expect upgrading Perl would be necessary. You should already have a working Perl version on your system.

Try searching for a perl-TermReadKey, or similar, package and install it with yum.

If you continue to have a problem, providing more details about your system might help someone address your specific problem.

Comment: Perl is not installed ...

$> yum list *perl-Ter*

perl516-perl-Term-UI.noarch 
rh-perl520-perl-Term-ANSIColor.noarch
rh-perl524-perl-Term-ANSIColor.noarch 
rh-perl524-perl-Term-Cap.noarch 
rh-perl526-perl-Term-ANSIColor.noarch
rh-perl526-perl-Term-Cap.noarch
rh-perl526-perl-Term-Table.noarch

Comment: @Janette, if I understand you, you mean that Term::ReadKey is not installed. Your posted error message already tells us that. That is just a separate Perl add-on module, not Perl. You seem to be trying to install Perl, which even if it worked, wouldn't install the module that you are missing. What does _yum search readkey_ show you? My CentOS shows _perl-TermReadKey_, which is what I think you need to get installed. The git package seems to not contain that as a dependency.

Comment: I'm rebuilding the server again... and will try again...


============================= N/S matched: readkey =============================
perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 : A perl module for simple terminal control

Answer (score 1):

[Some SCL packages require the Optional channels](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html/3.0_release_notes/chap-installation#sect-Installation-Subscribe-Optional):

> Some of the Red Hat Software Collections 3.0 packages require the Optional channel to be enabled in order to complete the full installation of these packages. For detailed instructions on how to subscribe your system to this channel, see the relevant Knowledgebase articles at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/392003 for Red Hat Subscription Management […]

The listed set of SCL packages and their Optional channel requirements apparently are slightly out of date.

(There is a package search feature on [access.redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/) which should help to address such issues.)